# using .one() on multiple classes

Tags: jquery, click

I have multiple divs with the same class name, but once one is clicked I don't want my function to happen again if another with the same class is clicked again.

```
$('.js-item').one( "click", function() {
    console.log('clicked once');
    // do something only once even if a div with the same class is clicked again
});
```

Is there a way for .one() to happen only once on all my classes? Because at the moment it applies just once but each time an individual div with that class name is clicked.

I need these divs to have the same class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `off()` on all those classes after executing your logic:

```js
$('.js-item').one("click", function() {
  console.log('clicked once');

  // do something only once even if a div with the same class is clicked again

  $('.js-item').off('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-item">click me!</div>
<div class="js-item">click me!</div>
<div class="js-item">click me!</div>
<div class="js-item">click me!</div>
<div class="js-item">click me!</div>
```

Using this method makes the `one()` redundant, so you can revert back to the standard `on()` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, will put as accepted answer after time allows me

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-item').on( "click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.js-item').removeClass('classAdded');
    $this.addClass('classAdded');
});
```

You could trick this way.

Comment: This won't do what the OP requires. It just stops the default behaviour and the event bubbling up the DOM. It doesn't stop you clicking on multiple `.js-item` elements and having the event handler run